# TFS 11 local, git remote

Tags: git, tfs, bitbucket

i was wondering if there is a chance to have localy a TFS 11 installation and remotely git(bitbucket).
TFS 11 has all i need to do my work.
But i want the projects on bitbucket for remote access if needed.

Is there a way??

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a Local Workspace with TFS 11 that shares the GIT repository directory, it will work very well.

Local workspace doesn't need you manually check-out a file, so you can share the same directory as where a change will be made from GIT it won't be an issue from the TFS side (which wouldn't be the case with TFS/VS 10).

So you need TFS11 AND VS11.

If you want to stick with VS10, you'll have to use two separate directories for TFS and GIT then manually merge from one to another or use the TFPT Online command to update the TFS Workspace from the GIT content.

Comment: That is correct. I think i should use a tfs branch to develop and a "main" to merge to. This main will be the shared directory with the git repository. This way i have a clean development branch and merge only thinks to the main and then to git. Changes comming grom git will be pulled to this main branch and commited to tfs, then merged with the dev branch. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a git-tf(s) bridge. With it -- you can commit to TFS normally and use the bridge to fetch TFS commits in a git repository. I use https://github.com/nodirt/git-tf for commiting to TFS from git, but your scenario would need only fetching from tfs and pushing to a remote repository (bitbucket).

For example, copying commits from TFS and pushing them to bitbucket:

```
git remote add bitbucket <bitbucket_url>
git tf fetch
git push bitbucket master
```

If you made changes to bitbucket and want them commited to TFS -- you should commit them through git-tf. Be sure to use rebase before pushing.